# What happens if I forget to save a change to an activerecord model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If I do something like this in AssetsController:

```
def change
  @asset=Asset.first
  @asset.param="new_param"
end
```

Here I never saved changes to this Asset instance.    Is @asset simply a ruby object that will disappear when the change method is over and so therefore changing some aspect of the ruby object will have no effect on the database?  Also, does the database connection to the Asset table automatically get closed when the method finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is @asset simply a ruby object that will disappear when the change
>   method is over and so therefore changing some aspect of the ruby
>   object will have no effect on the database?

Yes.

> Also, does the database connection to the Asset table automatically
>   get closed when the method finishes?

Rails manages the connection for you, closing it when it feels it's appropriate to do so. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html for more information.